# Property 'canActivate' in type 'AuthGuardService' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'CanActivate'

Tags: angular, async-await

Property 'canActivate' in type 'AuthGuardService' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'CanActivate'

```
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {
  constructor(public authService: AuthService, public router: Router) {}
  async canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ):
    Promise<boolean | UrlTree | Observable<boolean | UrlTree>> {
    if (!await this.authService.chechAuthenticated()) {
      this.router.navigate(['login']);
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

giving error:

> Property 'canActivate' in type 'AuthGuardService' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'CanActivate'.

Comment: duplicate ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49328056/ts2416-property-canactivate-in-type-myguard-is-not-assignable-to-the-same-p

Comment: No, actually in that question it is not dealing with async function, but mine is async `async canActivate`, that is creating the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't change the signature using async,  instead you can write a function in which it awaits the result and returns true or  false, you can then  call  this  function  from canactivate.

```
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {
   constructor(public authService: AuthService, public router: Router) {}
   canActivate(
       route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
       state: RouterStateSnapshot
   ){
        if(!isAuthenticated())
           this.router.navigate(['login']);
           return false;
        }
        return true;
   }
   async isAuthenticated() : bool {
      return Promise<boolean | UrlTree | Observable<boolean | UrlTree>> {
           return await this.authService.chechAuthenticated();
      }
   }
```

}

You can do something like this, please note that the above code is for getting an idea only, this is not tested, may contain compilation issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {
  constructor(public authService: AuthService, public router: Router) {}
  async canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Promise<boolean | UrlTree> {
    let result = await this.authService.chechAuthenticated();
    if (!result) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

this way my AuthGuardServie Worked.

Answer (score 0):

When flagging a function with "async", you cant return anything else but a Promise, so having "observable" as one of returning options will break the "canActivate" guard function, just remove everything but promises on return type  if you want to make the function async.